# Как получить уникальное число для каждого объекта в системе?

Tags: delphi

`Уникальное число объекта := currentThreadId + Integer(Tobject(self));`

только такая формула все равно вызывает дубли как этого избежать.

подойдет любой способ который сгенерирует уникальное число для текущего объекта. пробовал через `AllocateHwnd` - слишком долго работает при частых вызовах

вот мой файл:

```
1111111111
222222222222
333333
4444444
5555
```

- Заходит первый объект берет - `1111111111`
- Записывает что он этой строкой управляет - `1111111111:1`
- Делает запись в файл

```
1111111111:1
222222222222
333333
4444444
5555
```

- Заходит 2й берет свободное и файл становится таким:

```
1111111111:1
222222222222:2
333333
4444444
5555
```

- Дальше 1й вернет файлу управление, файл станет:

```
1111111111
222222222222:2
333333
4444444
5555
```

- Дальше 2й вернет файлу управление

```
1111111111
222222222222
333333
4444444
5555
```

Comment: Для чего это нужно? По смыслу это GUID? - вот и используйте GUID .

Comment: @MBo
 именно число нужно 32 битное желательно кто (какой объект) владеет одной из записью с общего файла

Comment: И эти объекты могут относиться к разным процессам?

Comment: @MBo Да ............

Comment: Пока что по вопросу впечатление, что вы гвозди микроскопом забиваете и спрашиваете как его поудобнее за штангу держать. Опишите задачу полнее.

Comment: А как вы потом собираетесь использовать этот ID? По нынешнему описанию это просто признак, что запись захвачена, а кем  - неважно.

Comment: 16-разрядное уникальное значение (таблицы хэндлов окон и т.п.тоже, наверное, до сих пор 16-разрядные ): `GlobalAddAtom`

Comment: Вы можете писать инкрементный ид в сам файл? Файл у вас сам по себе ресурс гарантирующий однопоточный доступ (если будете монопольно открывать).

Comment: Из более безумных вариантов - можно использовать время (вплоть до миллисекунд) + еще какой то уникально генерируемый идентификатор. `GetTempFileName` - вернет уникальное имя файл, только не забудьте его потом удалить. Написать свой генератор случайных чисел

Answer (score 1):

> число нужно 32 битное желательно кто (какой объект) владеет одной из записью с общего файла

Навскидку, это число равно номеру записи из этого файла. Гарантированна уникальность, никаких коллизий, монотонность.

Далее, если нужно распределить записи по пулу объектов, можете просто последовательно это сделать (Объект 1й, 2й, 3й ... Nй, 1й, 2й, 3й ... Nй, 1й, 2й, 3й ... )

Comment: номеров в файле нет. записи разной длины позиция постоянно меняется где начинается запись

Comment: То есть можете пройти файл и все пересчитать первым делом. Вы же не хотите сказать, что у вас вместо нормальной БД (типа SQL), все лежит в самописном файле с конкурентным доступом?

Comment: база тут только все усложнит. мне нужен просто уникальный хандел который генерится во время работы проги

Comment: а если что то удалится то обратно все индексы пересчитывать.
а если кто то просто открыл файл и удалял или подобавлял  туда обратно все посбивается. да и какая разница  ну серьезно. файл у меня или база или я говорю про что как получить число уникальное на машине. например Handle или как-то скомбинировать эти 2 числа  currentThreadId  Integer(Tobject(self));